# Interval of convergence? (Relatively simple question)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

What is the interval of convergence of the power series:

$\dfrac{(-1)^{(n-1)}x^n}{n^3}$

I know it should be |x| < 1, but does that mean the interval of convergence is $(1,-1)$ or $(-1,1]$ or $[-1,1]$ or something else entirely?

I really hate series's! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In general, $|x| < 1$ means $x\in (-1,1)$

Comment: Right, that's what I normally assume, but I have been wrong before with series's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are correct that the radius of convergence is $1$. But you need more information to decide between $(-1,1), [-1,1), (-1,1],$ and $[-1,1]$. In particular, you need to specialize $x$ to the values of the endpoints and try to see what happens.

For instance, let's look at the right endpoint, $x = 1$. Then you are looking at
$$ \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} \cdot 1}{n^3} = -\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^3}.$$
Does this converge or diverge? Through a method of your choice (perhaps by using an alternating series test), you should be able to decide that this last series converges. And so $x = 1$ should be included in your interval.

You must also check $x = -1$. You might notice that the cases look sort of similar, and this is not a mistake.

Comment: So I found out that it converges at x = 1 AND at x = -1, meaning the interval would be [-1,1] right? I just want to be sure!

Comment: @TheOneWhoCould yes, that's right.